# CakePHP 1.3: $this->validates not validating

Tags: cakephp

I am attempting to manually validate an array from within the model, but validation is successful regardless of what invalid data I populate in the array.

In my CustomerLocation model I am trying to validate $data:

```
$this->create();
$this->set($data);
if (!$this->validates()){
    //some action if validation fails
}
```

The $data in this case is a simple array:

```
Array
(
[location_number] => 125-Knoxville - M
[packing_notes] => Test
[packing_label_message] => packing message
[length] => 4
[width] => 4
[height] => 4
[weight] => 4
[shipping_carrier] => UPS
[shipping_service] => 2nd Day Air
[ship_date] => 
[id] => 768
[row] => 4
)
```

The $data above contains none of the required fields for the CustomerLocation model, so it should totally fail validation.

The source of this $data is an imported .csv row.  When I validate from a baked Cake form for this model, the validation works.

Is my $data array not formatted properly for $this->validates?  I would expect it to fail rather than pass if that were the case.

Any advice is certainly appreciated!

Comment: what are your validation rules? I am pretty sure there's your mistake

Comment: Without seeing your validation rules I'm guessing you need to add the 'required' option to your validation rules, which is probably what @mark is getting at. You'll want to read here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed to have:

```
'required' => true
```

in the validation rules for each field.  The `notempty` rule only applies when Cake is validating from a form, apparently. I should have posted my rules originally. I'm sure someone would have caught that.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I think you need to change `$this->set($data);` to:

```
$this->set(array('CustomerLocation' => $data));
```

CakePHP uses the first level of the array to determine which model(s) to validate against.

As none of the keys match a model name (ie. you don't have a `LocationNumber` or `PackingNotes` model), no validation rules are being found or applied.

Comment: Sadly, same results, though I think you are right that $data would need to be structured like that.  It seems to ignore whatever data I throw at it, at least from the model anyway.

Comment: @deizel: thats wrong. you dont need the model alias. if the array is flat it will automatically unflatten the array and parent it with the model alias (see line 1132 of model class).